# How many five letter words can be formed from the letters of the word INFINITESIMAL?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have $4I,2N,1F,T,E,S,M,A,L$.

Word of type: 
$AAAAB=8C1*\frac{5!}{4!}=40$

$AAABB=\frac{5!}{(3!*2!)}=10$

$AAABC=\frac{8C2*5!}{3!}=560$

$AABBC=\frac{7C1*5!}{(2!*2!)}=210$

$ABBCD=\frac{2C1*8C3*5!}{2!}=6720$

$ABCDE=9C5*5!=15120$

My answer is $40+10+560+210+6720+15120=22660$

But the answer is $22260$.  I don't know where I am making mistake?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  There must be an error in the answer key.

Comment: @Akul sharma; great question. Can you elaborate why you divided it into 5 sections and why you did 7c1 in part 4. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The exponential generating function for the number of words is
$$f(z) = \left( 1 + z + \frac{1}{2!} z^2 + \frac{1}{3!} z^3 + \frac{1}{4!} z^4 \right) \left( 1 + z + \frac{1}{2!} z^2 \right) (1+z)^7$$

On expansion, the coefficient of $z^5$ is $1133/6$, and 
$$\frac{1133}{6} \times 5! = 22,660$$
so your answer is correct.

Comment: can you explain why the OP use 8c2, 7c1 2c1*8c3 etc in his answer? (I asked the OP but he didn't reply) thank you